# Proper way to update mongodb document from REST

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, database-design

simply I have `AngularJs client`. He wants to use every API using **CRUD** architecture. For example:

```
GET /user
GET /user/:id
POST /user
PUT /user/:id
DEL /user/:id
```

This is all endpoints he want to use for my schema.(using MongoDB database).

I have **user** schema like (simplified):

```
{
    id : ObjectId("..."),
    name: "Foo fooer",
    itemIds : [
       ObjectId("..."),
       ObjectId("..."),
       ObjectId("...")
    ]
}
```

and schema **Items**(do not need to show for questions).

We need to *add/remove* `itemsId` from `user.itemIds`.
Client wants to create new schema **userItems**:

```
{
   id : ObjectId("..."),
   userId : ObjectId("..."),
   itemID : ObjectId("...")
}
```

and He want to remove `user.itemIds` from user schema and create 4 CRUD endpoints /userItems.

I think this wrong approach, normalizing the mongo database.

But I don't know which one of these is better from both sides(client and server).
1) Create 2 endpoints `POST /UserItem`, `DEL /UserItem` to update items in `user.itemIds`.

2) Update `user.itemIds` using existing API `PUT /user`, but client needs to send whole Array of *itemsIds* to update it(if there are many this is probably bad approach.

Client say these 2 approaches are bad, and he only know his SQL REST archictere(where everything is normalized). How can I prove him, that he is wrong? Because he said to me this: 

`Server to adapt to the client and not vice versa.`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api) is a good article about RESTful API.

In brief, your RESTful API should:

- Focus on resource
- Make sense
- Consistence

For example:

- When you want to add an item to an user: find the user first, not the other way around. So, `POST users/:userId/items/` to add a new item to user is good. Or, `DELETE users/:userId/items/:itemId` to remove an item from the user.
- When you want to find all the users who have this specific item: `GET /items/:itemId/users/`.